# How to Display Post tags separate with a tag in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tags

this is my data in database :

```
{
    id:1,
    title:"post title",
    content:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae, ab.",
    tags:"DISH, MENU, FOOD, TASTY"
    
}
```

in display time want to separate every keyword of tag with its own href tag like this:

```
http://example.com/search?tag=[tag keyword] 
want like this >> ( http://example.com/search?tag=DISH)
```

i am using react

[want to achieve this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3p2lK.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can start off by splitting the tags like this:

```
const data = {
 id:1,
 title:"post title",
 content:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae, ab.",
 tags:"DISH, MENU, FOOD, TASTY"
}

tags = data.tags.split(",");
```

After that we can create links like this:

```
render() {
  const url = 'http://example.com/search?tag=';
  return (
    tags.map(tag => {
      <a href={`${url}${tag.trim().lowercase()}`}>{tag.trim()}</a>
    })
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First split the `tags` field using `var splitting = tags.split(",")`
Then use a for loop to iterate over `splitting` and form the url/layout you want